# How do I knit into word with this error statement?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am having issues with knitting from rmarkdown into Word.

I keep getting this error statement-

```
Error in assert_package("as_flextable", "flextable") : 
  `as_flextable` requires the "flextable" package. To install, type:
install.packages("flextable")
Calls: <Anonymous> ... as_flextable -> as_flextable.huxtable -> assert_package
Execution halted
```

My code is

```
fit<-lm(earnings~gender+education, data = CPSSWEducation)
summary(fit)
knitr::kable(summary(fit)$coefficients)
huxtable::huxreg(fit)
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Well, did you try to install the `flextable` package?

Comment: It Worked. Thank you, still learning this coding life